# Ejector Tank Safe Cleaning Additives

Tags: sewer, septic

Wondering if there are any suggestions for a safe additive that can be flushed into a sewage ejector tank that can help break down waste (even toilet paper). Getting some awful foul smells - going to double seal it with another layer of silicone, but would love suggestion on an enzyme/other type additive that helps break it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additives don't help much, if at all.

Check gaskets and seals, as you've stated. Also check the [stack vent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain-waste-vent_system): The ejector pump tank must be [properly vented](https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/plumbing/venting-a-sewage-ejector-tank_o). This is true of all waste plumbing, to prevent buildup of gases.

For some other tips on reducing odor, see [InspectAPedia](https://inspectapedia.com/odor_diagnosis/Sewage_Pump_Odors.php).